# Validation is not working properly in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just created a simple input fields with one button and I have added validation for that.When I click `apply` button without values it should display error box and should not go inside `if(ack)` condition.
In my code error boxes are displaying but after that its going inside `if(ack)` method even there is no values.What I did wrong?

```js
function applyLeave() {
  debugger
  var ack = true
  $('.required').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      $(this).addClass('inputBorder')
      var ack = false
    }
  })
  if (ack) {
    var newLeaveDetails = {};
    newLeaveDetails = {
      a: $('#levType').val(),
      b: $('#levFrom').val(),
      c: $('#levTo').val(),
      d: $('#levDuration').val(),
      e: $('#uploadDoc').files[0],
      g: $('#LevReason').val(),
    }
    console.log(newLeaveDetails)
    var ajaxObj = JSON.stringify({
      LeaveDetails: newLeaveDetails
    });
    console.log(ajaxObj)
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '',
      async: true,
      data: ajaxObj,
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: function() {
        $(".success").html("Leave applied successfully!");
        $('.success').show();
        window.setTimeout(function() {
          window.location.href = '/leave/employeeleavelist'
        }, 1000);
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("Try Again")
      }
    })
  }
}
```

```css
.inputBorder {
  border-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="row border" id="applyLeave">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <label class="col-xs-12">Leave Type<span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
      <select type="text" id="levType" class="col-xs-12 form-control required"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <label class="col-xs-12">Available/Taken</label>
      <input type="text" id="levTaken" class="col-xs-12 form-control levTaken" readonly="readonly">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <label class="col-xs-12">Date From<span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
      <input type="date" id="levFrom" class="col-xs-12 form-control levFrom required">
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <label class="col-xs-12">Date To<span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
      <input type="date" id="levTo" class="col-xs-12 form-control levTo required">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <label class="col-xs-12">Duration(Days)</label>
      <input type="text" id="levDuration" class="col-xs-12 form-control levDuration" readonly="readonly">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <label class="col-xs-12">Supporting Document</label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2" id="uploadDoc">
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 ">
      <label class="col-xs-12">Reason<span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
      <textarea id="LevReason" class="col-xs-12 form-control addCc required" rows="2"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row  pull-right btnMarginTop">
    <button class="btn btn-primary applyLevBtn" onclick="applyLeave()">Apply</button>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You are defining new variable inside each loop. Just remove `var`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the `var ack` into `ack` inside the each function .Global `ack` not replace with `each()` function `ack` .beacause you are declare the both varaibles are a new one.

```js
function applyLeave() {debugger
     var ack = true
     $('.required').each(function () {

         if ($(this).val() == "") {
             $(this).addClass('inputBorder')
             ack = false
         }
     })
  
     if (ack) {
         var newLeaveDetails = {};
         newLeaveDetails = {
             a: $('#levType').val(),
             b: $('#levFrom').val(),
             c: $('#levTo').val(),
             d: $('#levDuration').val(),
             e:$('#uploadDoc').files[0],
             g: $('#LevReason').val(),
         }
         console.log(newLeaveDetails)
         var ajaxObj = JSON.stringify({ LeaveDetails: newLeaveDetails });
         console.log(ajaxObj)
         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: '',
             async: true,
             data: ajaxObj,
             contentType: 'application/json',
             success: function () {
                 $(".success").html("Leave applied successfully!");
                 $('.success').show();
                 window.setTimeout(function () {
                     window.location.href = '/leave/employeeleavelist'
                 }, 1000);
             },
             error: function () {
                 alert("Try Again")
             }
         })
     }
 }
```

```css
.inputBorder{
 border-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="row border" id="applyLeave">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                        <label class="col-xs-12">Leave Type<span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
                        <select type="text" id="levType" class="col-xs-12 form-control required"></select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                        <label class="col-xs-12">Available/Taken</label>
                        <input type="text" id="levTaken" class="col-xs-12 form-control levTaken" readonly="readonly">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                        <label class="col-xs-12">Date From<span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
                        <input type="date" id="levFrom" class="col-xs-12 form-control levFrom required">
                    </div>
                   
            </div>
            <div class="row">  
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                        <label class="col-xs-12">Date To<span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
                        <input type="date" id="levTo" class="col-xs-12 form-control levTo required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                        <label class="col-xs-12">Duration(Days)</label>
                        <input type="text" id="levDuration" class="col-xs-12 form-control levDuration" readonly="readonly">
                    </div> 
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                        <label class="col-xs-12">Supporting Document</label>
                         <input type="file" class="form-control col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2" id="uploadDoc">
                    </div> 
                                       
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 ">
                        <label class="col-xs-12">Reason<span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
                        <textarea id="LevReason" class="col-xs-12 form-control addCc required" rows="2"></textarea>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row  pull-right btnMarginTop">
                <button class="btn btn-primary applyLevBtn" onclick="applyLeave()">Apply</button>
                
            </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are declaring 'ack' variable two place one is method level and another is local for each function,And  you are checking the condition on method level 'ack' variable that value is always true.That's why the 'if' block is executing.

```
var ack = true
$('.required').each(function () {

     if ($(this).val() == "") {
         $(this).addClass('inputBorder')
         var ack = false
     }
})
```

Solution you need to remove the var sign into local variable like below

```
var ack = true
$('.required').each(function () {

     if ($(this).val() == "") {
         $(this).addClass('inputBorder')
         ack = false
     }
})
```